# jquery ajax: only can get the first parameter from server side, why?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var data = { 'id': event.id, 'd': event.date };


$.post("/event/renew/", data, function(result) {                             
                            alert(result);
                            },"json"
                        );
```

The date is alright, but when I use ajax to post data, only id was able to fetch from server, why?

Comment: We definitely need to see more code to be able to answer this.

Comment: the JSON serialization on the server my be incorrectly formatting the JSON object - check your server code...

Comment: In line with what Tesserex mentioned, can you show an example response of what `result` would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually serialize your data to mimic 'regular' post data like so.

`var data = 'id='+event.id+'&d='+event.date;`

it should end up looking like this

`id=value&d=value`

then pass `data` to your post array and you will be able to access the variables like a 'regular' post data.

`$_POST['id']` or `$_POST['d']`